# join omitting output lines when input sorted numerically

Tags: unix, join

i have two files, aa and bb:

```
 $ cat aa 
84 xxx
85 xxx
10101 sdf
10301 23

 $ cat bb
82 asd
83 asf
84 asdfasdf
10101 22232
10301 llll
```

i use the join command to join them:

```
 $ join aa bb
84 xxx asdfasdf
```

but what expected is 84, 10101 and 10301 all joined.
Why only 84 has been joined?

Comment: @qiuxafei edited the question's tagging -- join is not a part of bash, but a standard UNIX tool accessible from any shell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a lexicographical sort rather than a numeric sort.

To do this as part of the process:

```
$ join <(sort aa) <(sort bb)
```

This gives the output:

```
10101 sdf 22232
10301 23 llll
84 xxx asdfasdf
```

Comment: Does join support numeric order？

Comment: @qiuxiafei no, join does not support numeric order.

Answer (score 7):

You failed to include the fact that an error message is output:

```
$ join aa bb
join: file 2 is not in sorted order
84 xxx asdfasdf
join: file 1 is not in sorted order
```

You can use a normal lexicographic sort:

```
join <(sort aa) <(sort bb) | sort -k1,1n
```

Comment: not all implementations give this error -- some just fail silently.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid sorting, then you can zero pad with awk:

```
join \
 <(awk '{printf("%05d %s\n", $1, $2)}' aa) \
 <(awk '{printf("%05d %s\n", $1, $2)}' bb) \
| awk '{print int($1),$2,$3}'
```

Generates this output that preserves the original sort order:

```
84 xxx asdfasdf
10101 sdf 22232
10301 23 llll
```

You want to avoid sort, because Unix sort is O(n log n).